# Triggering multiple functions on a single queue

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Can I trigger multiple azure function on a single queue trigger.
Use case is that i am storing auth token in a queue, and multiple functions take up the token to call the different endpoints respectively. 
Or will the first one grab the message (token) and remove it from the queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this scenario, I would  use ServiceBusTrigger function. 
You can create a topic in a Service Bus, then for this one topic you can have multiple subscribers. 
So, even if 1 subscriber has finished going trough the messages, you can still have a subscriber which has not even started once and don't worry about this subscriber missing any message.

**EDIT**

Useful links

- [ServiceBusTrigger Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger---c-example)
- [Topics and Subscribers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions#topics-and-subscriptions)

Answer (score 1):

@dhruv Yes you can create multiple functions with the same queue, all works in parallel as likewise event grid subscribers, which queue you're using, is it storage queue or service bus etc?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a durable function for this.